# java.lang.VerifyError in android api < 21(KitKat)

Tags: java, android, xmpp, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing this   issue when am trying to open my app below the lollipop version of Android, am really stuck with this issue. so kindly help me out from this issue Thanks in advance

[image: this]

Comment: Add log and code here for more help

Comment: just click the above statement for it'd show the log

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Log and see what's causing the VerifyError. The cause is probably there is some method in a java.lang class that is not supported on the android SDK level you are using.